# how to have a different storage class for each pvc of a statefulset replicas?

Tags: kubernetes, statefulset, storage-class

I have a kubernetes cluster, 3 zones, a Truenas used for each zone.
I have 3 storage class (1 for each TrueNAS).
How can I have a statefulset with 3 replicas in each zone ? Pod is correctly deployed in each zone using node affinity but all PVC automatically gets the same storage class and therefore all persistent volumes are created in the same TrueNAS.
I have tried allowedTopologies without any success.

Comment: You must use a single storage class, since you only have one `volumeClaimTemplate`.

Comment: so it is not possible ?